# FullCalendar hide time in week timeline view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there a way to hide the time in a timeline view. In the month timeline you only see the days and no time, but in week timeline the time is also displayed.

I want it to be the same in week timeline. I need this because all my events are all-day events, so no need to display the time axis.

Desired result:

**Resource | Mon 1/12 | Tue2/12 | Wed 3/12 | Thu 4/12 | Fri 5/12 | Sat 6/12 | Sun 7/12**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have solved it by using duration and slotduration in a custom view:

```
defaultView: 'customWeek',
views: {
    customWeek: {
        type: 'timeline',
        duration: { weeks: 1 },
        slotDuration: {days: 1},
        buttonText: 'Custom Week'
    }
},
```

See also http://jsbin.com/mogefixege/edit?js,output for code

Answer (score 2):

You can use **basicWeek** versus **agendaWeek** view [See available views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)

http://jsfiddle.net/e78b944d/1/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'basicWeek' /* versus 'agendaWeek' */
});
```

Comment: I need the timeline views from the scheduler addon. In basic view or agenda view I cannot use resources. See also http://jsbin.com/qotecavuka/edit?js,output.