# Hide time header in resourceTimelineWeek view for Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using `resourceAreaColumns` and have `slotDuration` set to `'24:00:00'` for `resourceTimelineWeek` since I have exclusively allDay events for that view. This results in two rows for the header, one for date and one for time. Is it possible to get rid of the time? It is totally unnecessary to show 12am for each day when the events are set to allDay. I've only been able to figure out how to hide the date, but I don't want to do that.

Note: This is not a duplicate of the following:
[FullCalendar hide time in week timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049979/fullcalendar-hide-time-in-week-timeline-view)

Timeline view and resource timeline views work differently.

Here is the screenshot of header row.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the slot duration using days instead of hours:

```
    slotDuration: { days: 1 }
```

This causes the calendar to omit the time row from the display.

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzpaVxK

Comment: hello, same situation here. Notice the two non-overlapping events on first line in day view, and then switch to 'week' view. They appear OK in this case but I need to switch off the header line with hours somehow since it is totally useless and disturbing 

https://codepen.io/vladimir-nikolchev/pen/xxPyyYM?editors=0110